# Is it a good idea to use EF with Supabase?

Tags: .net, entity-framework, supabase

I am creating an application with .NET and Supabase.
I would like to take advantage of Supabase's Postgres database.
The flow of my application is that the Frontend authenticates in Supabase, but subsequent requests always go through the Backend. That means that any data retrieval is done from the Backend and then I send it back to the frontend. I understand that this may not be the common flow but my business logic requires it.
I have thought about using EF for migrations and DB operations. But I doubt it is a good idea.

I already have my backend set up
Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

It seems like there's support for [using postgresql with EF](https://www.npgsql.org/efcore/)

Your flow seems logical to me as I understand it, so I would not worry about it too much.